# jquery datatable filter on server side processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, filtering

```
    if (oTable.fnSettings().oFeatures.bServerSide == true) {
         console.log('filterdata', filterData);
         var settings = oTable.fnSettings();
            $(oTable[0]).on('preXhr.dt', function ( e, settings, data ) {
                    var filter = [];
                        Object.keys(filterData).forEach(function(key,index) {
                           filter.push({name: key, value: filterData[key]})

                        });
                        $.extend(data, {
                            filter: filter
                        })
            console.log('testdraw', settings.iDraw);
        });
```

Hey guys am trying to draw the filter on the first time when the page render and am using this code for the server side processing but i couldnt get it running the filter using the default filters i created for my datatable . it actually run filter when on event but not on default when page render . please help me guys thanks

Comment: `$(oTable[0]).trigger('preXhr.dt')`

Comment: thank u but it didnt work :( any other suggestions????